# How to properly use indexing in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization, explain

I'm running a fairly simple auto catalog

```
CREATE TABLE catalog_auto (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
    make varchar(35),
    make_t varchar(35),
    model varchar(40),
    model_t varchar(40),
    model_year SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED,
    fuel varchar(35),
    gearbox varchar(15),
    wd varchar(5),
    engine_cc SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED,
    variant varchar(40),
    body varchar(30),
    power_ps SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED,
    power_kw SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED,
    power_hp SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED,
    max_rpm SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED,
    torque SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED,
    top_spd SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED,
    seats TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED,
    doors TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED,
    weight_kg SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED,
    lkm_def TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED,
    lkm_mix TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED,
    lkm_urb TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED,
    tank_cap TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED,
    co2 SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    INDEX `gi`(`make`,`model`,`model_year`,`fuel`,`gearbox`,`wd`,`engine_cc`),
    INDEX `mkt`(`make`,`make_t`),
    INDEX `mdt`(`make`,`model`,`model_t`)
);
```

The table has about 60.000 rows so far, so, nothing that simple queries, even without indexes, couldn't handle.

The point is, i'm trying to get the hang of using indexes, so i made a few, based on my most frequent queries.

Say i want `engine_cc` for a specific set of criteria like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT engine_cc FROM catalog_auto WHERE make='audi' AND model='a4' and model_year=2006 AND fuel='diesel' AND gearbox='manual' AND wd='front';
```

`EXPLAIN` says:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref                                 | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | catalog_auto | ref  | gi,mkt,mdt    | gi   | 408     | const,const,const,const,const,const |    8 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

The query is using `gi` index as expected, no problem here.

After selecting base criteria, i need the rest of the columns as well:

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_auto WHERE make='audi' AND model='a4' and model_year=2006 AND fuel='diesel' AND gearbox='manual' AND wd='front' AND engine_cc=1968;
```

`EXPLAIN` says:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref                                       | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | catalog_auto | ref  | gi,mkt,mdt    | gi   | 411     | const,const,const,const,const,const,const |    3 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

It selected a KEY but NOT using the index. The query however, is very fast(1 row in set (0.00 sec)), but since the table doesn't have that many rows, i assume even without indexing, it would be the same.

Tried it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_auto WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM catalog_auto WHERE make='audi' AND model='a6' AND model_year=2009);
```

Again, in `EXPLAIN`:

```
+----+--------------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table        | type            | possible_keys      | key     | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | catalog_auto | ALL             | NULL               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 59060 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | catalog_auto | unique_subquery | PRIMARY,gi,mkt,mdt | PRIMARY | 4       | func |     1 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
```

Still NOT using any index, not even PRIMARY KEY. Shouldn't this, at least use the PRIMARY KEY?

Documentation says: MySQL can ignore a key even if it finds one, if it determines that a full table scan would be faster, depending on the query.

Is that the reason why it's not using any of the indexes? Is this a good practice? If not, how would you recommend indexing columns, for a `SELECT *` statement, to always use an index, given the above query.

I'm not much of a MySQL expert, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Using MySQL 5.5 with InnoDB.

Comment: Why the complex 3rd query and not the simple `SELECT * FROM catalog_auto WHERE make='audi' AND model='a6' AND model_year=2009;` which would probably use an index on `(make, model, model_year)`, i.e. your `gi` index?

Comment: Ah, I read the wholke question now. OK, the confusion comes from the explain `Using Where`. This means that it **does** use the index (but not only the index.) It also has to do some lookups on the table to retrieve the est of the columsn. Since it is fast, you should not worry at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm basically saying the same answer that @DStanley said, but I want to expand on it more than I can fit in a comment.

The "Using index" note means that the query is using *only* the index to get the columns it needs.
The absence of this note doesn't mean the query isn't using an index.

What you should look at is the `key` column in the EXPLAIN report:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref                                       | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | catalog_auto | ref  | gi,mkt,mdt    | gi   | 411     | const,const,const,const,const,const,const |    3 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

The `key` column says the optimizer chooses to use the `gi` index. So it *is* using an index. And the `ref` column confirms that's referencing all seven columns of that index.

The fact that it must fetch more of the columns to return `*` means it can't claim "Using [only] index".

Also read this excerpt from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-output.html:

> - Using index
>
>   The column information is retrieved from the table using only information in the index tree without having to do an additional seek to read the actual row. This strategy can be used when the query uses only columns that are part of a single index.

---

I think of this analogy, to a telephone book:

If you look up a business in a phone book, it's efficient because the book is alphabetized by the name. When you find it, you also have the phone number right there in the same entry. So if that's all you need, it's very quick. That's an *index-only* query.

If you want extra information about the business, like their hours or credentials or whether they carry a certain product, you have to do the extra step of using that phone number to call them and ask. That's a couple of extra minutes of time to get that information. But you were still able to find the phone number without having to read the entire phone book, so at least it didn't take hours or days. That's a query that used an index, but had to also go look up the row from the table to get other data.

Comment: I read that part, however it makes more sense now. Actually this is exactly what i wanted to know. Whether the fact that it chose a key, and not showing that it uses index, means that it is still using it, even if it's partially. Very nice explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a MySQL expert, but my guess is that the index was used for the *row lookup*, but the actual data has to be retrieved from the data pages, so an additional lookup is necessary.

In your first query, the data you ask for is available by looking *only* at the index keys.  When you ask for columns that aren't in the index in the second and third queries, the engine uses the key to do a SEEK on the data tables, so it's still very fast.

With SQL performance, since the optimizer has a lot of freedom to choose the "best" plan, the proof is in the pudding when it comes to indexing.  If adding an index makes a common query faster, great, use it.  If not, then save the space and overhead of maintaining the index (or look for a *better* index).

Note that you don't get a free lunch - additional indices can actually *slow down* a system, particularly if you have frequent inserts or updates on columns that are indexed, since the systme will have to constantly maintain those indices.

Comment: Since its only a catalog, it can only contain as much data as there are makes and models on the market, which is fairly limited, so maintaining is not an issue, when adding a new row from time to time. The first query (or alike), is quite frequent, so the `gi` index helps a lot. The second query however, is used on an even more frequent base. I thought of indexing all the columns together, but i doubt it's a good idea. Furthermore, the app i'm building, relies a lot on the catalog, which in the end, will generate even more queries to it. How about indexing all of them separately?

Comment: A covering index may help, but the only way to know is to try it and measure the performance difference.  Until then you're just speculating since the optimizer can do whatever it thinks is best.  I don;t think separate indexes will help a `SELECT *`.